# Unable to direct my login result to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to C# and the asp.net world. So the question i am going to ask might be pretty lame, hope you all will bear with me :). Ok so i was reading through a book and understanding the basics of how authentication and authorization happens within asp.net.

Now i have defined my authentication and authorization as follows within my web.config;

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/LogOn" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" name="MyCookies" />
</authentication>
<authorization>

  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>

</authorization>
```

and then i went ahead to create my login form. Which is as follows;

```
<form method="post" action="../Home/LogUser">
<fieldset>

<legend>Log On</legend>
<p>User Name</p>
<p><input type="text" name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" size="30"/></p>

<p>Password</p>
<p><input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" size="30"/></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Log On"/></p>
</fieldset>
 </form>
```

My issue is that since i have defined to deny anonymous users in my web.config, when i try to submit my form which directs to the controller, it comes back to the log in page. How do i handle this situation? maybe i have understood the whole log in paradigm in asp.net in which case i humbly appreciate an explanation on that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to asp.net. I particularly like the MVC framework. Hope you do to.

Many points to suggest

1) if you are using MVC framework, this approach is NOT recommended. A far superior approach is to apply `[Authorize]` attributes to controllers and / or methods you want to close off to non-authenticated users.

This approach allows great flexibility to decide where your users can go anonymously, where they can go authenticated, and where only certain roles can go `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]`

2) If you want to continue with web.config settings and for authentication locations, to allow users access to specific locations, add this code to web.config

```
<location path="~/Home/">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

3) What I don't understand from your question was your intent. If you want the user to be able to login, you should open `~/Account/Logon` and your Logon Form should (Ideally) post there.

Comment: hi Dave, right on the spot. I was trying to direct to a different URL to handle the authentication part. Now its working. And appreciate the point on using the [Authorize] attribute. Will go ahead with that. Thx again mate.

Comment: thx mate. coming from a java/struts background i must say i am loving the fact of how everything is so nicely laid out and allows you to set up and get up and running with minimal effort